# Add-Migration throws error with no configuration found

Tags: entity-framework

When I try to create a new migration using EF Code-First the package manager console gives me an error saying: 'No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Project.DataAccess'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).'

I've previously used this method on THIS project successfully and the project do have a Configuration file with all the correct inheritance.

I also tried specifying all the parameters -Name, -StartupProjectName etc. but no change. When trying to re-enable migrations VS is not successful creating the Configuration with inheritance from my context-class.

Any suggestion on this issues? Using EF 4.3.1 and Code-First

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was resolved by installing EF 4.3.1 using the Package Manager Console. I had done a manual upgrade and for some reason that didn't do the trick.